# Bind ArrayList<ArrayList<>> in Custom Adapter in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I want to make a custom adaper which will contain multiple `String` and an `ArrayList<ArrayList<GeofenceDetails>>`.

```
private ArrayList<Geofences> geofencesArrayList;
geofencesArrayList = new ArrayList<Geofences>();
assetNameArrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<GeofenceDetails>>();

geofencesArrayList.add(new Geofences(id,name,type,assetNameArrayList));
adapter = new GeofenceNameListAdapter(getActivity(),geofencesArrayList);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
geoListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my custom adapter

```
 public class GeofenceNameListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<Geofences>> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<Geofences> geofences;
    //song list and layout
    private LayoutInflater view;
//    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public static final String PREFERENCES = "RPREFS";
    SharedPreferences sharedprefs = null;
    private String ord_id = null;
    private String email = null;

    public GeofenceNameListAdapter(Activity context,
                                   ArrayList<Geofences> geofences) {

        super(context, R.layout.layout_geofence, geofences.size());
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        finder_sharedprefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

        finder_ord_id = finder_sharedprefs.getString("org_id", null);
        finder_email = finder_sharedprefs.getString("email", null);

        this.context = context;
        this.geofences = geofences;
    }
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_geofence, null, true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtType = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.type);rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

    txtTitle.setText(geofences.get(position).getTitle());
    txtType.setText(geofences.get(position).getType());

    return rowView;
}
```

I can see everything on `geofencesArrayList`. Here I am printing data of `geofencesArrayList`

```
    for (int l = 0; l<geofencesArrayList.size(); l++) {
        Log.d("GEOFENCE_DETAILS", geofencesArrayList.get(l).getId().toString());
        Log.d("GEOFENCE_DETAILS", geofencesArrayList.get(l).getTitle().toString());
        Log.d("GEOFENCE_DETAILS", geofencesArrayList.get(l).getType().toString());
    //  Log.d("GEOFENCE_DETAILS", geofencesArrayList.get(l).getPoints().toString());
        Log.d("GEOFENCE_DETAILS", geofencesArrayList.get(l).getEnforcedData().toString());
}
```

But the problem is Adapter doesn't display any data. I think something went wrong in my custom adapter but I couldn't figure out it.

I appreciate you advice. Let me know How can I create a custom adapter to show multiple strings and `ArrayList<ArrayList<>>`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things on code quality: A) naming ... there is no point in putting the exact type into your names B) you also do **not** want to use the specific implementation class on your type; you better write `private List<Geofences> geofences = new ArrayList<>();` directly. Much easier to read and use!

Comment: No data is showing because you are sending wrong arraylist in your adapter. You defined the GeofenceNameListAdapter constructor with ArrayList<Geofences> whereas initializing the adapter with ArrayList<ArrayList<GeofenceDetails>>().

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat. I will do that.

Comment: I don't see `setAdapter` method call. Do you have it?

Comment: @Alvi I didn't get you. I am sending geofencesArrayList in my adapter which  is the exact one.

Comment: @Ircover Yes I have geoListView.setAdapter(adapter); But I didn't add it to the code here.

Comment: @anuradha Glad to hear that ;-)

Comment: try removing the line adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
notifyDataSetChanged() is mainly used when BaseAdapter class in extended.
Check this link for more : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5092426/2632867

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`ArrayAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) constructor that gets 3-rd parameter as view resource ID, but you are putting there array size.

```
super(context, R.layout.layout_geofence, geofences.size());
```

First of all, change constructor call (place 3-rd parameter something like `R.id.list_item` or just use 2-parameter constructor).

Then you should override `getCount` method in your `GeofenceNameListAdapter` class.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return geofences.size();
}
```